# dpkg / apt-get won't remove/purge libreoffice completely. Over 200MB remains

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, libreoffice

I've removed successfully:
writer, calc, draw, impress, and math, but the startcenter can't be removed...
I've tried sudo dpkg -P libreoffice-startcenter, sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-startcenter, sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*.* nothing neither works... In /usr/lib, it contains over 200MB of something... I"m on UbuntuMATE, and it's the stock installation...

sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*.* spits out a bunch of thinkgs marked for removal, and advised me to try sudo apt-get autoremove, which also does nothing...

other programs can be removed as usual, it's only libreoffice...

Any advice?

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*`should be enough.

Comment: well it's obviously not... it remains installed, it starts, it uses more then 200MB disk space... it wouldn't be a big deal, if my entire system wasn't being loaded to RAM at startup... Having only 8GB of ram...

Comment: Thanks, and never mind it worked... the problem was I was trying to remove libreoffice*.* instead libreoffice*... (PEBKAC)